# Replace sqlite3.3.6-5 for sqlite3.7.0-1 on centos5

Tags: linux, installation, centos, rpm

I want to update my sqlite3 version. I'm using centos5 (VPS requeriment), I have a new version downloaded (.rpm) and a previous installed (with the os) I have this error.

[image: image of my problem]

Well, I have noob on centos distributions, and dont know well the yum, rpm yet, but I cant found a solution for this.. Any idea? Sorry my bad english.

Is a test environment, I will havent problem with install the two versions on same time if these are posible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, searching and searching, I have found a solution here:
http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/atomic-x86_64/sqlite-3.7.0.1-1.el5.art.x86_64.rpm.html

I dont know why anybody press negative reputation to my question, I give all dats possible, attach a image, I try to be clear.. Of course, thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `rpm -Uvh` to upgrade the package, not install a second copy. You may also want to try `yum localinstall <rpmfile>` instead to help with dependency issues.